# cannot convert const wchar_t to 'const_char' for argument 2 in MessageBOX etc etc

Tags: c++, directx

I'm learning DirectX for a project for university, My compiler however shows this error:

```
"10 C:\Dev-Cpp\projectdirectx\main.cpp cannot convert `const wchar_t*' to `const CHAR*' for argument `2' to `int MessageBoxA(HWND__*, const CHAR*, const CHAR*, UINT)'"
```

I don't understand this at all, I don't know what I did wrong, What i'm attempting to do is a simple messagebox, Here's the code:

```
#include <windows.h>

int WINAPI WinMain(HINSTANCE hInstance,
                   HINSTANCE hPrevInstance,
                   LPSTR lpCmdLine,
                   int nShowCmd)
{
      MessageBox(NULL, L"testing testing",
                 L"C++", MB_OK);


      return 0;
}
```

What do I do?

Answer (score 2):

You are building an ANSI build, but using a Unicode literal. Either use regular string literals (drop `L` prefix in front), or switch to a Unicode build.

Answer (score 0):

Just remove the L prefix from the strings.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that you are trying to invoke wide character version of `MessageBox` function, which is not the case in your build environment. Just remove the `L` macro in the function call and it should work.